# Error when calling apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce() in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm getting an error when trying to call `apoc.spatial.geoCodeOnce()` on neo4j Desktop version 5.2 on Windows.

Here is the code I'm trying to run (apoc version 5.2.1):

```
call apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce('44113') yield location
return location.longitude, location.latitude
```

Here is the error that is returned:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce`: Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

I have tried manipulating the neo4j.config file, along with experimenting with different versions of neo4j/apoc.

I was expecting the output to provide longitude/latitude coordinates for the zipcode 44113.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

This [Knowledge Base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/ldap-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) may be related.

To quote from the article:

> The problem appears when your server uses a self-signed certificate.
> To workaround it, you can add this certificate to the list of trusted
> certificates for your JVM. The Root Certificate will need to be added
> to the Java CAstore using keytool.
>
> keytool -import -alias *alias_name* -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts
> -file _path_to_cer_file